# Generating paths from proximity map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity, raster-conversion

I'm trying to generate paths from proximity map in QGIS, is there a way to convert the light areas into vector lines?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Raster calculator, i-click some of your light areas and pick a threshold value. I use 30, I should have chosen a smaller to get thinner green areas:

   ("Proximity map@1">30)*1 + ("Proximity map@1"<=30)*0
2. SAGA:s skeletonize

[image]